# Regarding the limitaions of "Listen Server"

Tags: networking, game-engine, ping

Let's say that I have a game server located in my country which is hosted by my ISP. For example, I pinged their game server and I got 10 ms ping, and let's say the game features the ability to host the game by your machine (listen server) instead.

So let's say that my friend is going to be hosting that game and I'm going to join him and rely on his connection to me, and suppose he lives just next to my home and we have the same ISP. Is it possible that I'm going to get ping times of around 10 ms just like dedicated server or will be higher? If yes, is it because the limitations of the machine itself, or what could be the cause?

Comment: If you know he's next door, likely it should be less than 10ms. That per se is not limitation of the machine. You need to make sure though that such thing is indeed permitted by your ISP. Try `ping ` and `traceroute` and see if that's allowed.

Comment: wow. you're right! I tried "tracert" on command prompt and it showed me the hops between me and my neighbor and I got 12 ms avg. it only takes two hops to reach my neighbor and back! it goes like this: My house====>ISP Backbone====>Neighbor's house.

Comment: To me 12ms to go to your neighbour from same ISP for a single hop  or two hops is 'very high'!! it should be like 4-5ms!! What access medium are you using? Cable Modem?

Comment: Really? I think this is a pretty normal ping. compared back to where I had ADSL service to my house. I was always getting ping times between as high as 35ms even when I ping my ISP first or two hops, I get ping of 35ms avg. and I heard that ADSL can add to the already ping times due to

Comment: Oh ok - may be I am used to ping times of 10ms a few hops away(on ADSL). but if 12ms works for you - may be you are good! :)

Comment: lol. it's not a big deal. no one can notice the lag under 70ms anyway!